# Which programming/scripting languages to learn to design the user interface of a Moodle website?

Tags: php, user-interface, plugins, moodle

I have a task of designing the user interface for a Moodle website.

I have a cursory understanding of `HTML5` and `CSS3`. But I am at zero skill-level in `PHP`.

I have been reading through the general "how-things-work-at Moodle" in the [Developer docs](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overview#Coding_Standards) for a few hours now, but I am yet at a loss at this:

**What programming languages shall I need to design just the user interface of the website? Is PHP essential? Where do I start?**

I did learn that the `modules/plugins` and `API` are written in `PHP` (reference), and that `HTML` and `CSS` ARE used ([reference](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=257793)), and I hope that I won't have to use PHP.

**What if the existing API does not provide `methods/functions` for some types of questions, blocks etc. , which means I will have to code for them. So shall I have to use `PHP` for that?**

I am done with downloading and installing `Apache2 server` and `MySQL`, going to install `PHP` and then confirgure `Eclipse` for Moodle development. **What shall I do next?**

Comment: I think 'User Interface' is comprehensive word for moodle. Can you give some brief what you want to create in user interface of moodle?

Comment: @SumanBogati I want to extend a theme in order to display certain types of data in a certain way.

Comment: Please read the documentation provided on these links it may helps to you, http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme and http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme

Comment: @SumanBogati Thank you very much. I gave it a read, it helped a lot. But I have been examining the files in the theme I want to extend. It popped a couple of questions in my mind, so I posted those [questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712304/moodle-how-to-change-the-default-region-on-the-page-where-the-block-is-displaye) here. Please see if you can answer them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In moodle,

The core scripting language for server side is PHP,

For client side, HTML, CSS and javaScript are using.

With moodle, we can add our custom functionality in various way, like

**module, blocks, plugins and theme.**

You should have good knowledge about PHP and bit knowledge about HTML/CSS when you are working with module, blocks and plugin.

If you choose a theme way, you should have good knowledge about HTML/CSS, and bit knowledge about PHP.

By the theme way, You can give good look and feel, and can add limited functionality to moodle.

So its all depend on what exactly you want in user interface for moodle.

If you want to tweak kind of custom menu, profile dash board, and add slider then I would suggest for theme way.

After installed required PHP version, you just need to download the moodle, and install it in your server.

For download stable [moodle](http://download.moodle.org/).