# How to change the default region on the page where the block is displayed?

Tags: php, layout, themes, moodle, renderer

I want to *extend a theme* in *Moodle*, and want to *change the place (on the page) where a question (in a quiz) is displayed.*

I have seen the structure of the theme I want to extend. Firstly, I believed that I will have to change the `default region` (from regions like `$side-pre` and `$side-post` etc.) for the block containing the question, for the *layout option* (like `front-page`, `standard`, `course` etc. ... [list of all options](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes_overview#theme_options_table) here) *which represents the page for the quiz.*

1. But I can't find the *layout option* which *represents the page
   where a question in a quiz is displayed.* **So can somebody suggest
   me from the linked table which layout option should I choose, where
   I can simply change the region where the question is displayed**
   (e.g. if the question is being displayed in the `$side-pre` region,
   I want to change it such that it is displayed in the `$side-post`
   region)
2. Or is the the wrong way around it? Shall I have to *override* the
   `renderer` of the    *question plugin*? **If so, how can I find out which
   part of the renderer controls the default-region where the question
   block will be displayed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the second option - http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer#Finding_renderers_to_override

In summary

create a theme directory with 2 files

```
theme/overridetest/config.php
theme/overridetest/renderers.php
```

In config.php

```
$THEME->name = 'overridetest';
$THEME->parents = array('standard', 'base');
$THEME->rendererfactory = 'theme_overridden_renderer_factory';
```

Then in renderers.php have something like this, I'm not sure which function to override so have picked view_page as an example

```
class theme_overridetest_core_renderer extends core_renderer {

}

include_once($CFG->dirroot . '/mod/quiz/renderer.php');

class theme_overridetest_mod_quiz_renderer extends mod_quiz_renderer {

    public function view_page($course, $quiz, $cm, $context, $viewobj) {
        $output = '';
        // Change the output here.
        return $output;
    }
}
```